# Projection Matrix only goes from 0 to 1

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, directx

I am working on my Projection Matrix in c++.

If I use a Orthogonal Matrix, the Axis range goes from 0 to my screen size.
Now if I use my Perspective Matrix, the Axis range goes from 0 to 1.

This is not good if I want to position my objects. I could divide their movement with the width and height, but I think that there should be a better solution just like by using an orthogonal matrix.

```
                T aspect = (right - left) / (top - bottom);
            T xScale = 1.0f / tan(fov / 2.0f);
            T yScale = xScale / aspect;

            return Matrix<T>(
                yScale, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                0.0f, xScale, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                (left + right) / (left - right), (top + bottom) / (bottom - top), zFar / (zNear - zFar), -1.0f,
                0.0f, 0.0f, (zNear * zFar) / (zNear - zFar), 0.0f);
```

That's my Perspective Matrix

```
            T farNear = zFar - zNear;

            return Matrix<T>(
                2.0f / (right - left), 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                0.0f, 2.0f / (top - bottom), 0.0f, 0.0f,
                0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f / farNear, 0.0f,
                (left + right) / (left - right), (top + bottom) / (bottom - top), -zNear / farNear, 1.0f);
```

That's my Orthogonal Matrix calculation

So how can I fix it so that if I use my perspective matrix, the axis range goes from 0 to my screen size instead of 0 to 1.

Comment: That question is written very unclear. Both code snippets you provide calculate a _perspective_ projection matrix. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The bottom matrix does not look like a perspective projection matrix to me. The `m33` component is **1.0** and the rest of the last row is zero. Usually `m32` would be **-1** or **1**.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: you are right. it is an ortho matrix.

Comment: In my opinion, question that involve some specific libraries or stuff should mention this, not only by tagging. Without the tag there would be no clue what you are talking about

Comment: Sorry, I was talking about a Projection Matrix. I fixed the title and added more informations.

Comment: By the way, the proper term is orthographic projection -- not orthogonal matrix. Orthogonal is a related term, but only means at right-angles and many different types of matrices may be orthogonal (e.g. a typical modelview matrix).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### This range you mention does not work that way in a perspective projection.

To figure out the width and height of your viewing volume, you need to know your field of view (in GL we typically define this using a vertical angle and aspect ratio) and the distance from the near plane; width and height will vary with distance down the z-axis.

#### The following diagram illustrates the situation:

[image]

In an orthographic projection, the viewing volume has the same width and height no matter how far or close you are to the near clip plane. In this sort of projection, a point `(x,y,...)` at z=1.0 is equa-distant from one edge of the screen as the same point `(x,y,...)` at z=100.0, and thus you can establish a single X and Y range for all points.

With a perspective projection as discussed [here](http://www.alpcentauri.info/projection_transformation.htm), the farther a point is from the near plane, the more pushed toward the center of the screen it gets because the visible coordinate space expands.

[image: http://www.alpcentauri.info/perspectivePic.jpg]

The only way you are going to have a single range of visible X and Y coordinates is if you keep Z constant. *But if you keep Z constant, then why do you want a perspective projection in the first place?*